# Update or append URL parameters rather than replace entire URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am attempting to build a week calendar. Currently the calendar has forward and backward links that work by building a new URL with `?date=` appended to the end. Example:

```
<a href="<?php get_current_url() ?>/?date=2014-07-23">Next week</a>
<a href="<?php get_current_url() ?>/?date=2014-07-09">Prev week</a>
```

I would also like to add a filter the calendar, allowing only certain event types to be displayed on the calendar. I have come up with the following using the GET method:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
  <select name="type">
    <option selected disabled value=''>Type</option>
    // event option stuff
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When submitted, this form simply rebuilds a new URL with `?type=<something>` added to the end. If the URL already has a date parameter, my form ignores it. For example:

http://www.example.com/?date=2014-07-16

Becomes:

http://www.example.com/?type=dinner-date

Likewise, the week navigation ignores the filter.

Is there a simple way to get the filter and the navigation links to work together?

For example, if `?date=` already exists, then `&type=` is appended to the URL. And if one or both parameters already exist then the values are simply updated.

Comment: Why not use a hidden field for the date? `<input type="hidden" name="date" value="2014-07-23" />`

Comment: @SamMonk yes I think that's a great idea for handling when a date is already present and the form is submitted. But how would it work the other way round? I.e. when there is an event type selected first. Also, how would it work if both a date and type exist and a new type or new date is selected?

Comment: @user1444027 The date will get updated with the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make the assumption that you could use jQuery:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://www.example.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo date;?>" />
    <select name="type">
        <option selected disabled value=''>Type</option>
        <!-- event option stuff -->
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="buildLink($('#date').val());">
    <br>
    <input type=button onclick="buildLink('2014-07-23');" value="Next week" />
    <input type=button onclick="buildLink('2014-07-09');" value="Prev week" />
</form>
```

And then this is a simple Javascript function that submits the form, and depending on what you choose, the date is changed in the form before it is submitted:

```
function buildLink(date) {
    $('#date').val(date);
    $('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: Do the next and prev week links need to be inside the same form? On my calendar's layout they are not in the same position.

Comment: I believe they can be anywhere you need them to be. They can even still be links like this `<a href="#" onclick="buildLink('2014-07-09');">Prev week</a>`